# How is Databricks builtin Hivestore accessible by any databricks workspace cluster?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, hive-metastore

When I create a table in Databricks built in hive_store the data is accessible using any cluster.
Where is this table data stored? Is there some built in memory assigned at Databricks workspace level?

Comment: you can always create a table and describe it to look for its location, or data -> hive_metastore -> default -> table_name -> details tab - mostly it will be in `dbfs:/user/hive/<table-name>` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks store the table data to your connected cloud providers AWS/AZURE/GCP.

You can use any metastore either internal or external, but the data is always store in your cloud.

> Regardless of the metastore that you use, Databricks stores all table
> data in object storage in your cloud account.

Please check this documentation [reference](https://docs.databricks.com/lakehouse/data-objects.html#:%7E:text=Regardless%20of%20the%20metastore%20that,storage%20in%20your%20cloud%20account). I hope it answer your question.